# CandidateArchive for model-assisted multi-fidelity global search algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, unit-testing, interface

For my research I'm working on global search methods where a *candidate* solution can have it's *fitness* (=score) evaluated in multiple *fidelities* (=accuracy levels). The goal of the `CandidateArchive` is to keep a clear overview of which candidate solutions have been evaluated under which fidelities. A candidate is an `ndim`-dimensional vector of floating point values, with `ndim` known in advance.

During its usage, new candidates will be added to the archive together with the fitness score for some fidelity-level. High(er) fidelity fitness scores may be added later. The archive can give back all candidates that have a fitness score for a given list of fidelities.

A trivial example of the stored data at some point might look like this:

```
candidate  | high-fidelity | low-fidelity
-----------+---------------+---------------
(0.1, 0.2) | NaN           |  1.57
(0.2, 0.7) | 2.5           |  1.25
(1.5, 2.1) | NaN           |  2.78
(0.2, 1.1) | 3.8           |  4.31
(1.5, 0.5) | NaN           |  1.57
```

I feel like my interface design for this `CandidateArchive` is not what I want it to be, but don't quite know how I can improve it. Suggestions for tests (pytest/[hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) are also more than welcome.

```
import numpy as np
from warnings import warn
from collections import namedtuple


CandidateSet = namedtuple('CandidateSet', ['candidates', 'fitnesses'])


class CandidateArchive:

    def __init__(self, ndim, fidelities=None):
        """An archive of candidate: fitnesses pairs, for one or multiple fidelities"""
        self.ndim = ndim

        if not fidelities:
            fidelities = ['fitness']
        self.fidelities = fidelities

        self.data = {}
        self.max = {fid: -np.inf for fid in self.fidelities}
        self.min = {fid: np.inf for fid in self.fidelities}


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


    def addcandidates(self, candidates, fitnesses, fidelity=None, *, verbose=False):
        """Add multiple candidates to the archive"""
        for cand, fit in zip(candidates, fitnesses):
            self.addcandidate(cand, fit, fidelity=fidelity, verbose=verbose)


    def addcandidate(self, candidate, fitness, fidelity=None, *, verbose=False):
        """Add a candidate to the archive. Will overwrite fitness value if candidate is already present"""

        if len(self.fidelities) == 1 and fidelity is not None and verbose:
            warn(f"fidelity specification {fidelity} ignored in single-fidelity case", RuntimeWarning)
        elif len(self.fidelities) > 1 and fidelity is None:
            raise ValueError('must specify fidelity level in multi-fidelity case')

        if fidelity is None:
            fidelity = self.fidelities

        # Checking types to make sure they are iterable in the right way
        if isinstance(fitness, (np.float64, float)):
            fitness = [fitness]

        if isinstance(fidelity, str):
            fidelity = [fidelity]

        for fid, fit in zip(fidelity, list(fitness)):
            if tuple(candidate) not in self.data:
                self._addnewcandidate(candidate, fit, fid, verbose=verbose)
            else:
                self._updatecandidate(candidate, fit, fid, verbose=verbose)


    def _addnewcandidate(self, candidate, fitness, fidelity=None, *, verbose=False):
        if len(self.fidelities) == 1:
            fit_values = [fitness]
        else:
            fit_values = np.array([np.nan] * len(self.fidelities))
            idx = self.fidelities.index(fidelity)
            fit_values[idx] = fitness

        self._updateminmax(fidelity, fitness)
        self.data[tuple(candidate)] = fit_values


    def _updatecandidate(self, candidate, fitness, fidelity=None, *, verbose=False):
        fit_values = self.data[tuple(candidate)]

        if fidelity is None:
            fidelity = 'fitness'

        fid_idx = self.fidelities.index(fidelity)

        if verbose and not np.isnan(fit_values[fid_idx]):
            warn(f"overwriting existing value '{self.data[tuple(candidate), fid_idx]}' with '{fitness}'", RuntimeWarning)

        fit_values[fid_idx] = fitness
        self._updateminmax(fidelity, fitness)


    def getcandidates(self, num_recent_candidates=None, fidelity=None):
        """Retrieve candidates and fitnesses from the archive.

        :param num_recent_candidates:   (optional) Only return the last `n` candidates added to the archive
        :param fidelity:                (optional) Only return candidate and fitness information for the specified fidelities
        :return:                        Candidates, Fitnesses (tuple of numpy arrays)
        """

        if type(fidelity) in [tuple, list]:
            pass
        elif fidelity:
            fidelity = [fidelity]
        else:
            fidelity = ['fitness']

        indices = [self.fidelities.index(fid) for fid in fidelity]

        candidates = []
        fitnesses = []
        for candidate, fits in self.data.items():
            for idx in indices:
                if np.isnan(fits[idx]):
                    break
            else:
                candidates.append(list(candidate))
                fitnesses.append([fits[idx] for idx in indices])

        candidates = np.array(candidates)
        fitnesses = np.array(fitnesses)

        if num_recent_candidates is not None:
            candidates = candidates[-num_recent_candidates:]
            fitnesses = fitnesses[-num_recent_candidates:]

        return CandidateSet(candidates, fitnesses)


    def _updateminmax(self, fidelity, value):
        if value > self.max[fidelity]:
            self.max[fidelity] = value
        elif value < self.min[fidelity]:
            self.min[fidelity] = value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type hints

PEP484 type hints, such as `ndim: int`, will help better-define your interface.

### Mutability

Reading your code, the other members of `CandidateArchive` only make sense if `fidelities` are immutable. As such, don't make them a list - make them a tuple. One advantage is that you can safely give a default argument of `('fitness',)`, whereas you can't safely give a default argument that is a mutable list.

### lower_camel_case

`addcandidates` should be `add_candidates`.

### Logic inversion

```
        if tuple(candidate) not in self.data:
            self._addnewcandidate(candidate, fit, fid, verbose=verbose)
        else:
            self._updatecandidate(candidate, fit, fid, verbose=verbose)
```

Since you have both code paths here, put the positive one first so that you don't need a `not`:

```
        if tuple(candidate) in self.data:
            fun = self._update_candidate
        else:
            fun = self._add_new_candidate
        fun(candidate, fit, fid, verbose=verbose)
```

### Default arguments

```
    if fidelity is None:
        fidelity = 'fitness'
```

should be replaced with a default argument of 'fitness'.

### No-op code

```
    if type(fidelity) in [tuple, list]:
        pass
```

This can be made into an outer condition so that you don't need to `pass`:

```
if not isinstance(fidelity, (tuple, list)):
    if fidelity: ...
    else: ...
```